# Common Library for SOAP and REST

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

we are having SOAP and REST equivalent services exposed. I want to write a test cases in a way that I write it once and can check it for both SOAP and REST.

because each time there is more of some repetitive code for SOAP and REST and want to make consumer independent of it and focus more on its business details.

Can some one put there inputs on it. Or is something similar available?

Comment: sorry, can't get your points in what you are looking for

Comment: i m thinking of something which RestClient + SOAP Client